# How do I make my link list appear in order from top to bottom, not right to left?

Tags: html, css

How do I make the link list appear from top to bottom, instead of left to right? I've tried html spacing ( ) and such. It just isn't that professional, so I came here to ask how to do this.

```html
   <style>
body {
margin: 0;
font-family: "Yu Gothic", sans-serif;
transition: background-color .5s;
background-color: (0, 0, 0, 0.5);
background-image:url(image url here);
text-align: left;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #000000;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 278px;
height: 100%;
}

li {
float: left;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: white;
padding: 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.main {
padding: 16px;
margin-top: 30px;
height: 1500px; /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
<li><a href="#main"><img src="image url here" width="240 height="128"></a></li>
<li><a href="#home">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
 </body>
```

Comment: remove the `float:left` from your `li`

Comment: li {float: left;}
 remove this

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove the style

```
li {
 float: left;
}
```

it's works fine

```html
<style>
body {
margin: 0;
font-family: "Yu Gothic", sans-serif;
transition: background-color .5s;
background-color: (0, 0, 0, 0.5);
background-image:url(image url here);
text-align: left;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #000000;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 278px;
height: 100%;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: white;
padding: 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.main {
padding: 16px;
margin-top: 30px;
height: 1500px; /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
}
</style>
<body>

<ul>
<li><a href="#main"><img src="image url here" width="240 height="128"/></a></li>
<li><a href="#home">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need ?

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 font-family: "Yu Gothic", sans-serif;
 transition: background-color .5s;
    background-color: (0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 background-image: url(image url here);
 text-align: left;
}
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #000000;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 width: 278px;
 height: 100%;
}
li {
 display: block;
}
li a {
 display: block;
 color: white;
 padding: 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.main {
 padding: 16px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 height: 1500px; /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#main"><img src="image url here" width="240 height="128"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#home">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```